# Build with clang and gcc at same time in conan?

Tags: gcc, build, clang, conan

Can I set 2 compilers in conanfile.txt and build for 2 times by different compiler? Or set some option like : conan build . --compiler=gcc ; conan build . --compiler=clang ?

Answer (score 0):

I find method:
build install . -s compiler=gcc compiler.version=8
build install . -s compiler=clang compiler.version=11

Comment: I would suggest reading [using profiles](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/using_packages/using_profiles.html) section, from the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you @uilianries for your reminding, I will follow this doc and try.